# how to use consume node package created using commonjs, browserify and gulp in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I've created node package (a simple math library) using commonjs, browserify and gulp and published this package to npm. I want to publish both my source code and minified output to npm. Below is my code in github and published package in npm:

https://github.com/jyotiprasadpal/math-lib-test

https://www.npmjs.com/package/math-lib-test

I've installed this package to consume it in my angular project.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "math-lib-test": "^1.0.1",
    ...
  }
```

I'm trying to import as below in angular component:

```
import * as mathlib from './math-lib-test';
```

I'm getting below error.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module './math-lib-test'.
```

1. Can someone please help what mistake I'm doing in creating my node
   package before it is published to npm?
2. Have I consumed it correctly in my angular project?
3. What improvements can be done to my node package? I want to publish both source code and minified files to npm.

Please advice as I'm new to this area.

Comment: Try importing `'math-lib-test'`, as you're importing a module and not a file in your project.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Now, I'm getting new error when I open browser console...`ERROR TypeError: math_lib_test__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.add is not a function`

Comment: This would mean you're exporting your functions wrong.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 It now works. Thx. When I install the published package, I don't see node_modules folder inside the installed package directory although there is devDependencies in package.json? What could be the mistake? Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you installed your package with `npm` or `yarn` rather than just adding it to `package.json`?